# Pipeline in GCP Dataflow on G1-small instance getting warning

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a scheduled pipeline on Dataflow (jdbc to BigQuery) set to run on g1-small instance.

A few jobs were ran, but there is a warning in the log of each job:

`Running Dataflow jobs with shared-core instance types (g1-small, f1-micro) is not officially supported.`

All the jobs have been finished with no error, but I still getting that warning. Has anyone faced the same warning?

Answer (score 1):

As per your statement above, you are currently using **g1-small** shared-core machine type. I recommend you to use the `n1` machine type for best results, as it is suggested by [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#workers) for best practice.

You can also go to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/general-purpose-machines#n1_machines) to view the features of n1 machine types.

The `Running Dataflow jobs with shared-core instance types (g1-small, f1-micro) is not officially supported.` warning is an expected behaviour since f1 and g1 are not supported under [Service Level Agreement](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/sla) of Dataflow.